# Every arrow in category $\mathbf{SET}$ is regular

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

The questions reads : Show that an arrow $f$ is regular if it has either a left or right inverse, and prove that every arrow in category $\mathbf{SET}$ ,with domain $\neq 0$, is regular.

My confusion sets in if I assume that I have to make use of the first result, because in context of set theory, left inverse is "equivalent" to injectivity (right "equivalent" to surjectivity). So it boils down to showing that every function in $\mathbf{SET}$ is either injective or surjective, but this is not true as there are lots of function that is neither of them.

So if I was not suppose to make use of the first result, how do I construct an arrow $g$ so that $fgf=f$

Any hints or insight is deeply appreciated.

Cheers and thanks

Comment: Aren't regular maps closed under composition ? Then the epi-mono factorization should be of some help

Comment: Ahhh ok let me try: So first we decompose $f = gh$. $g$ monic, $h$ epi. What we want is a k, such that $fkf = f = ghkgh$. now using what I mention we can let k be the composite of the right inverse of $h$ and left inverse of $g$ ?

Comment: Use the axiom of choice.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets with $x_0\in A$ and let $f:A\to B$ be a function.

If $C$ denotes the image of $f$ then $\{f^{-1}(\{c\})\mid c\in C\}$ forms a partition of $A$.

According to the axiom of choice a set of representatives exists, i.e. a set $\{a_c\mid c\in C\}\subseteq A$ such that $\forall c\in C [a_c\in f^{-1}(\{c\})]$ or equivalently $\forall c\in C[f(a_c)=c]$.

Now let $g:B\to A$ be the function prescribed by $b\mapsto a_b$ if $b\in C$ and $b\mapsto x_0$ otherwise.

Then evidently $f\circ g\circ f=f$.